# Save row on out of focus is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jQgrid uses inline row editing. user can edit row on double clicking the row or pencil button click.I want to save editing row on row out of focus.

tried following option in inlineNav

```
restoreAfterSelect: false
```

but it is not working.

> jQgrid version : 4.13.5-pre - free jqGrid

Comment: **You should post the JavaScript code, which you use or the demo, which reproduce the problem.** `restoreAfterSelect: false` means *no call of `restoreRow`* on selection another row. *Multiple rows will stay unsaved, till the user clicks "Save" button. "Saving row on out of focus" is not possible at all, because 1) row can't have focus (only controls/input elements inside of the row). You have to combine logic in both `blur`/`focus` event handlers 2) `blur` and `focusout ` are processed in different way in different web browsers (in combination with `focus`).

Comment: @oleg how can I combine blur and focus events to save currently editing row on outside click ?

Comment: I tried to explain you that it's wrong way in my opinion at least in the common case, how you formulate it in your question. You can write long code, which will work good in 99%, but it will still not save the data in 1% of the cases and the user will be sure that the changes are successfully saved. I recommend you to change your requirements.